# Duplicate Magento order number

Tags: orders

A customer made a order but he got that same order number was already created in magento , so his order number was not imported in magento and was not sent to paypal .

After a research on magento blogs i found :

It's entirely normal to have one out of sequence like that, be previous to the current allocated numbers and a month or more old. The secret to it is that it was a logged in customer who didn't complete the order after a certain critical stage, came back, logged in and decided to finally buy.

The quote with the allocated Sales Order number uses that number for the Sales Order number.

can we make it so that it will not hapen again with any other customer please ?

Thanks 
Kuldeep !

Comment: hey kuldeep have to create a cron which will reset the order increment id once cron run.you have to do change in eav_entity table for this.